# Please Explain Deadlock Concept

Tags: java, deadlock

I was going through Java threads, specially the deadlock concept, I have found this below code:

```
public static void main(String... a) {

    final String o1 = "Lock ";
    final String o2 = "Step ";

    Thread th1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (o1) {
                    synchronized (o2) {
                        System.out.println(o1 + o2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    };

    Thread th2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (o2) {
                    synchronized (o1) {
                        System.out.println(o2 + o1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    };

    new Thread(th1).start();
    new Thread(th2).start();

}
```

Please explain what the program is doing as per my understandings a lock has been taken by one thread and trying to take another lock and the same is done by other thread , and when finally when we start two threads both got stuck up, Is there any other way to create deadlock of the above program, please advise and also the lock which is being taken in the above code is it the instance level lock.

Comment: To get a deadlock you should change the order (thread 1 acquires o1 then o2 whereas thread2 acquires o2 then o1).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following scenario:

- `th1` locks `o1` and is interrupted before it gets a chance to lock `o2`;
- `th2` locks `o2` and tries to lock `o1`.

Neither thread can make further progress, and you have a [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

The original version of your code (before the edit) had no possibility of deadlock, since both threads acquired the two locks in the same order (`o1` then `o2`).

Answer (score 0):

To create Deadlock, you need to create a situation where multiple threads are waiting for locks held by other threads. For example:

- Thread 1 needs Lock1 and Lock2
- Requests in order: Lock1, Lock2
- Thread 2 needs Lock1 and Lock2
- Requests in order: Lock2, Lock1

  1. Thread 1 requests Lock1.
  2. Thread 2 requests Lock2.
  3. Thread 1 gets Lock1.
  4. Thread 2 gets Lock2.
  5. Thread 1 requests Lock2.
  6. Thread 2 requests Lock1.
  7. Thread 1 cannot have Lock2, Thread 2 is holding it. /Thread 1 waits...
  8. Thread 2 cannot have Lock1, Thread 1 is holding it. /Thread 2 waits...

---

In your (first, unedited) example, both threads request the locks they need **in the same order** and this is very important. If Thread1 gets Lock1, Thread2 cannot get Lock2 and create Deadlock, because it is still waiting for Lock1. Deadlock is avoided, because both threads attempt to acquire locks in the same order.

In your (new, edited) example, Deadlock can happen as explained above.

Comment: Hi Sam , thanks a lot, in the end order of acquiring a locks matters the most,, could you also please advise how can i avoid the deadlock in this above program so that it can execute normal..!!

Comment: Hi Sam also please explain that here the synchronized is representing the instance level lock..!! thansk in advance..!

Comment: @user1338319 You could call it an "instance level lock"... but what's the point of that when it's happening in the main?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edited post, th1 could acquire o1 while th2 could acquire o2. Then both threads are waiting for the other to release the lock they have not acquired yet, and it never happens ==> deadlock.